# Multiline in sub-conditional math

Tags: amsmath

I have a very long conditional statement and I would like to make it multiline.  I know how to do:

```
\begin{equation}
    A=
    \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ x=1, x=2 \\
      2, & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

but would like something like:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to dispense with the "if" particle?

Comment: Typo on my end.  Question has been solved.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if }
       \begin{aligned}[t]
       x&=1\\
       x&=2
       \end{aligned}
\\
  2, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: What's the use of that `\!`?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Oh, this answer was given before `amsmath` was updated to make the `\!` unnecessary. I edited it

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    A=
    \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if           $x=1$}\\
         & \text{\phantom{if }$x=2$}\\
      2, & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this should do:

```
\begin{equation}
    A=
    \begin{cases}
      1, & x=1 \\
        & x=2 \\
      2, & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Or do I miss something?